# ListView simple list multiple choice not returning the right values

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to make a `ListView` simple list multiple choice, but when I choose for example the items number 1 and 3, the returned values will be number 1 and 2, if I choose any 5 random choices the returned values will be the first five values.

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = modeList.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        if (checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
            String tag = (String) modeList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            checkedItems.add(tag);
        }
}
```

And as I said, no matter what I choose **the values will always return the first items** of the list even if the choices are randomly selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparseBooleanArray` is bit tricky. You should use construction like this:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked= listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i <= checked.size(); i++) {
     if (checked.valueAt(i)) 
        yourListAdapterArray[checked.keyAt(i)];
}
```

Also, there is no need for that:

```
if (checked.valueAt(i) == true)
```

Better use simple:

```
if (checked.valueAt(i))
```

Comment: But can you tell me what was going wrong, and whats the difference between the two of them?? Regards